# Xamarin.ios initialize UIView

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using `Xamarin.iOS`. I have created `UIView` with a few `UITextField`s. I am looking for best way to initialize text value in these textfields from code.
I can pass text data in the constructor of `UIViewContoller`, but I don't have access to textFields inside it (they are null). I can change text value of textFields in viewDidLoad method.

I don't want to create additional fields in controller class to store data passed by constructor and use them in viewDidLoad. Do you know better solution ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't want to create additional fields in controller class to store
>   data passed by constructor and use them in viewDidLoad.

But that's how it's meant to be done.

Alternatively, you can create less fields/properties in your viewcontroller if you use a MVVM pattern:

```cs
public class UserViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set;}
}

public class UserViewController : UIViewController
{
    UserViewModel viewModel;
    public UserViewController (UserViewModel viewModel) : base (...)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        userName.Text = viewModel.Name;
        userTitle.Text = viewModel.Title;
    }
}
```

That's the kind of pattern which gives you a lot of code reuse accross platforms (android, WP, ...) and clearly separate concerns. It's a (very) little bit of extra code, but it's worth every byte.